# How to calculate statistics from dataframe and insert them into new dataframe, matching by name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) of every single NBA shot taken with columns of time, shot location, player, etc. (there are duplicates of player names because every shot taken is its own row) and I want to create a new dataframe with calculated figures from the original dataframe. The new dataframe will have one row per player with various statistics like "Total Shots" and "Make %".

I have created the new dataframe with just the names of players:

df_names = df1[['Player Name']].drop_duplicates()

And now I would like to know how to go through df1, count the shots taken per player, insert that into my new df_names as a new column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The feature of pandas that I'd recommend diving into is .groupby() ([pandas documentation for .groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)). Rather than doing these in two different operations, you can do them as one:

```
data = {'Player Name': ['Player 1', 'Player 1', 'Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 2', 'Player 2']
        , 'Shot Time': ['1/1/2022 10:00:0000', '1/1/2022 10:01:0000', '1/1/2022 10:02:0000', '1/1/2022 10:03:0000', '1/1/2022 10:04:0000', '1/1/2022 10:05:0000']
        , 'Shot Made': [True,True,False,False,True,False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_agg = df.groupby(['Player Name'],as_index=False)['Shot Time'].count()
```

[image]

You can group by Player Name and do various aggregations over your columns, such as counts of shot times for number of shots (as above), mode of position, average time between shots, etc.

Eventually, you may need to join multiple of these dataframes together. If so, you would use the .join() or .merge() function. Here's the pandas documentation about various ways to smoosh data together: [Pandas Join, Merge, Concatenate and Compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: So using this method I can create a bunch of dataframes with a "Player Name" column and the column of calculated values (calculated with the '.count()' . Is there a way to assign the calculation as a new column of a dataframe I already have?

Comment: Not between dataframes, but within the same dataframe, yes: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html What I usually do is do a dataframe per calculation type (e.g., one each for count across applicable columns, avg across applicable columns, sum across applicable columns, etc.) and join them together at the end

Comment: If this resolved your question, feel free to hit the accept button :)

Answer (score 0):

You should accept K. Thorspear's solution, as I am just adding to it.

You can aggregate on a groupby of the player name. Count the `'Shot Time'` column (will simply count how many times a player took a shot), then sum the `'Shot Made` columns (since True = 1, and False = 0, the sum will give the total made).

Then just divide those out to get a shot percent:

import pandas as pd

```
data = {'Player Name': ['Player 1', 'Player 1', 'Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 2', 'Player 2']
        , 'Shot Time': ['1/1/2022 10:00:0000', '1/1/2022 10:01:0000', '1/1/2022 10:02:0000', '1/1/2022 10:03:0000', '1/1/2022 10:04:0000', '1/1/2022 10:05:0000']
        , 'Shot Made': [True,True,False,False,True,False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.groupby(['Player Name']).agg({'Shot Time':'count', 'Shot Made':'sum'}).rename(columns={'Shot Time':'Shot Attempt'})
df['Shot %'] =    df['Shot Made'] / df['Shot Attempt']
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
             Shot Attempt  Shot Made    Shot %
Player Name                                   
Player 1                3          2  0.666667
Player 2                3          1  0.333333
```